# Regex for command match words

Tags: php, regex

I'm building an app with commands like `set my_key list of values`.

I'm stuck with the matching of "words"

My command always start with `set` and has parameters separated by spaces. Each parameter can have `-` or `_`or be wrapper between quotes (ex: "my custom parameter") to allow spaces or every other characters.

I'm using it in my code like that:

```
if (preg_match_all('^set\s(("(.*?)")|(\w+)+)?/i', $command, $matches)) {
  // some code  
}
```

Here is what I expect for differents possible values

```
$text                                      | return | $matches

set                                        | TRUE | []
set param                                  | TRUE | ['param']
set "foo foo_bar foo-bar 123 'bar" bar bar | TRUE | ["foo foo_bar foo-bar 123 'bar", "bar", "bar"]
set foo bar foo bar                        | TRUE | ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar']
set my-word                                | TRUE | ['my-word']
set my_word                                | TRUE | ['my_word']
setttttt                                   | FALSE
```

Here is the regex live example: 
https://regex101.com/r/IAcYWE/1

Comment: if i were you, i would separate the process in different steps. Actually your regex can only match a single param, to support multiple ones you'll probably need quite complex lookaheads or lookbehinds, whereas a simple `explode` on spaces after removing the "set" and after extracting what's in quotes will be as good

Comment: How are you planning on handling that "string ('bar') in a string ("foo foo_bar foo-bar 123 'bar'") in a string ($command)"-scenario in PHP without banging your head against the wall? You'll want to escape some of those quotes. Perhaps take a look at how CLI-argument parsers do the job, this is not such an unusual use-case.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. @ctwheels this is the regex i was looking for :) can you please submit the answer so I can accept it?
I will see how the project evolve, maybe an explode will be simple to process and maintain.

Comment: @Tib I've added an answer to your question (below). I've edited the regular expression to work better (faster, less steps, no unnecessary captures or matches). I've deleted my last comment containing the old regex since it works less well than the current one (below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Code

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/IAcYWE/5)

```
(?:^(set)|\G(?!\A)(?=\h+\S))(?:\h+(?|([\w-]+)|"(.*?)")|(?:\h*?$))
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
set
set 
set param
set "foo 123 'bar" bar bar
set foo bar foo bar
set my-word
set my_word
setttttt
```

#### Output

- Match 1

  - Group 1: `set`
- Match 2

  - Group 1: `set`
- Match 3

  - Group 1: `set`
  - Group 2: `param`
- Match 4

  - Group 1: `set`
  - Group 2: `foo 123 'bar`
- Match 5

  - Group 2: `bar`
- Match 6

  - Group 2: `bar`
- Match 7

  - Group 1: `set`
  - Group 2: `foo`
- Match 8

  - Group 2: `bar`
- Match 9

  - Group 2: `foo`
- Match 10

  - Group 2: `bar`
- Match 11

  - Group 1: `set`
  - Group 2: `my-word`
- Match 12

  - Group 1: `set`
  - Group 2: `my_word`

---

### Explanation

- `(?:^(set)|\G(?!\A)(?=\h+\S))` Match either of the following

  - `^(set)`

    - `^` Assert position at the start of the line
    - `(set)` Capture `set` literally into capture group 1
  - `\G(?!\A)(?=\h+\S)`

    - `\G` Assert position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
    - `(?!\A)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not a position at the start of the string (basically making `\G` match the position at the end of the previous match and **not** the start of the string)
    - `(?=\h+\S)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows matches

      - `\h+` Match one or more horizontal spaces
      - `\S` Match one non-whitespace character
- `(?:\h+(?|([\w-]+)|"(.*?)")|(?:\h*?$))` Match either of the following

  - `\h+(?|([\w-]+)|"(.*?)")` Match the following

    - `\h+` Match one or more horizontal whitespaces
    - `(?|([\w-]+)|"(.*?)")` Branch reset group (any subpatterns in groups share the same number/name/identifier). Match either of the following

      - `([\w-]+)` Capture the following into capture group 2

        - `[\w-]+` Match one or more of a character in the set `\w-` (any word character `\w` or the hyphen character `-`)
      - `"(.*?)"`

        - `"` Match the double quotation character `"` literally
        - `(.*?)` Capture any character any number of times, but as few as possible, into capture group 2
        - `"` Match the double quotation character `"` literally
  - `(?:\h*?$)` Match the following

    - `\h*?` Match any number of horizontal whitespace characters, but as few as possible
    - `$` Assert position at the end of the string

---

### Usage

A match is defined by **Group 1** being set. Parameters are defined by **Group 2** being set. Multiple **Group 2** matches may be present for each **Group 1** matches. Each **Group 2** corresponds to the most recent previous **Group 1** match.

Comment: Thank for that really detailed answer

Comment: @Tib you're very welcome. I edited my answer to fix some formatting issues, should be more legible now.